# Change SQLServer session timeout in web config to use external time source

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config, timeout

I have a web server and its session state is stored in a Sql Server. I need to change the timeout to use an external time source. How would I do this?

Comment: What you mean with external time source?

Comment: We have a table in our SQL Server that allows the user to specify what they want there timeout to be, so instead of specifying the timeout in the web config he wants the web config to go and look at the table and pull the timeout from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's not hard to do it. I suppose you're able to read that data from the table - related, as you said, to some User Preference - and to put this data in an int:

```
int myTimeout = [... read from DB];
```

It's enough to add this line after the login procedure has been completed (or even during the procedure):

```
Session.Timeout =  myTimeout;
```

Note: the Timeout is in minutes.

Comment: so for the read from DB we would put the database that the table is in then the actual table that the information is in correct?

Comment: Sorry I  didn't get what you mean. But you can set the Session Timeout outside the Web.Config, in any C# Page that has access to the HttpSessionState instance.